# Why in TypeScript generic specialized with class can be stored in variable specialized with different class?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create some sort of Bootstrapper with a static module dependency check. And can't figure out how to force TypeScript to distinct generics with different classes.

Code with example of the problem:

```js
interface IModule<Deps extends IModule<any> = any> {
    readonly resolver: Resolver<Deps>
    init(): void
}

interface IModuleFactory<Deps extends IModule, Mod extends IModule<Deps>> {
    moduleName: string
    new (resolver: Resolver<Deps>): Mod
}

class Resolver<Modules extends IModule> {
    readonly modules: Record<string, Modules> = {}

    add<M extends Modules, D extends IModule>(mod: M, fact: IModuleFactory<D, M>) {
        this.modules[fact.moduleName] = mod
    }

    get<M extends Modules, D extends IModule>(fact: IModuleFactory<D, M>): M {
        return this.modules[fact.moduleName] as M
    }

    all(): Modules[] {
        return Object.values(this.modules)
    }
}

class NoModule implements IModule<NoModule> {
    readonly resolver: Resolver<NoModule>
    init() {}
}

class Mod1 implements IModule<NoModule> {
    readonly resolver: Resolver<NoModule>
    init() {}
}

class Mod2 implements IModule<Mod1> {
    readonly resolver: Resolver<Mod1>
    init() {}
}

// Here is the problem. It's ok for TS
const resolver: Resolver<NoModule> = new Resolver<Mod2>()
```

Why is `Resolver` the same even if it's specialized with different directly non-related classes?

Comment: Hi, the same as what? Could you please clarify what you expected to happen?

Comment: I expect that `Resolver<NoModule>` is a different type than `Resolver<Mod2>` and last line in example should show an error because type is different

Comment: Code example in the question contains 3 errors. For `NoModule`, `Mod1` and `Mod2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) and not [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system): a type `A` and a type `B` are considered equal if they have the same *structure*, despite having different *names* or *declaration sites*. This is true for classes as well as interfaces, so the following compiles with no error:

```
class Foo {
    a: number = 1
    b: string = "x"
}
class Bar {
    a: number = 2
    b: string = "y"
}
const b: Bar = new Foo(); // no error here
```

`Foo` and `Bar`, despite being different classes at runtime (`b instanceof Bar` would return `false`), are seen as the same type in the type system.

---

The second thing to note here is that when a class `implements` an interface, it doesn't actually have an effect on the type of the class.  If your implementation is incorrect you'll get an error, but when it comes to how the compiler treats the class types, you might as well leave the `implements` clause off.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#32082](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32082) and issues linked within for more information.

So that means your three classes behave exactly the same as the following code, with `implements` clauses commented out (and I also  added the [definite assignment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions) operator `!` to suppress errors with `--strict`):

```
class NoModule //implements IModule<NoModule> 
{
    readonly resolver!: Resolver<NoModule>
    init() { }
}

class Mod1 // implements IModule<NoModule> 
{
    readonly resolver!: Resolver<NoModule>
    init() { }
}

class Mod2 // implements IModule<Mod1> 
{
    readonly resolver!: Resolver<Mod1>
    init() { }

}
```

And from here you should see what's coming.  The type `Mod1` is the same type as `NoModule`, since they have the same structure.  And therefore `Mode2` is the same type as `Mod1` because the only difference between them is that the second mentions `Resolver<Mod1>` instead of `Resolver<NoModule>`, but `Mod1` and `NoModule` are the same type.  So all three classes are the same type and you will not get any errors.

---

If you want two types to be considered different by the compiler, you should in general give them different structures.  See [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-prevent-two-types-from-being-structurally-compatible).  One way to do this is to give them differently typed properties to "brand" them;

```
class NoModule implements IModule<NoModule>
{
    readonly name = "NoModule" as const
    readonly resolver!: Resolver<NoModule>
    init() { }
}

class Mod1 implements IModule<NoModule>
{
    readonly name = "Mod1" as const
    readonly resolver!: Resolver<NoModule>
    init() { }
}

class Mod2 implements IModule<Mod1>
{
    readonly name = "Mod2" as const
    readonly resolver!: Resolver<Mod1>
    init() { }

}

// error!
const resolver: Resolver<NoModule> = new Resolver<Mod2>()
```

Another way for classes is to give them a [`private` or `protected` property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#private):

```
class NoModule implements IModule<NoModule>
{
    private prop: any
    readonly resolver!: Resolver<NoModule>
    init() { }
}

class Mod1 implements IModule<NoModule>
{
    private prop: any
    readonly resolver!: Resolver<NoModule>
    init() { }
}

class Mod2 implements IModule<Mod1>
{
    private prop: any
    readonly resolver!: Resolver<Mod1>
    init() { }

}

// error!
const resolver: Resolver<NoModule> = new Resolver<Mod2>()
```

Either way should work for you.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoaXpgFzQDsBXAWwCMBTAJ2gF5oBGDbaM-CAFyoEsCBzOtABEADyEYAvhlCQYAITA00mbHkKlKNegCZm2NtE49+goQE9x6KemDwCnVvgVbCFAO5xEACgCUAbmgAekDCJGoqeBoAC2oKDHj0DF4OagAzMGAKaABJAFl4ABMiEAoAHgARCgAHGAoRFIICmDzC4rKwAjMAPkEO7pQ9LCoKMAK7EDNoYYh4EAA3anwAJQoZ+eoK6oguwehebg5ffDn4bgLJBOS0jKyWopLYDI5IswroOoamnPz7igAaaC5d71CiNZo-NoVLo9ZQsEitEoAOTAJAo7C4vD4uwI7i801mCyoy1WBI25S6PnwuQuiRs4Cg0BWa0JpSBH1BXzubRhu2Go3Gk3hvwgxNsVAKpSMmIBuR69GQ1l2owluTZILBgIB5WBn3BCIoXS8QqpuQB6WAHHwXIeTxeFRlsp8AxULCwHCi3AgADohW0IABtc0cH365GogC6giFu0VLugfAoHFZat1mug2vZGutBq8QatEJtFrt5QdFJNztd2GGHCIVAI0HdnpDwsDT2bbTDFEjkEB1LjsZYYBAICOgP9kdhlamidr9YA8mQAFYUC1euZDoirLyN72+koQHwxmkJaT0mCI+AFrLBbgkKolVEEDh636lC9XnoYSdDEZjAgTadmWoABCYkgKoN9L31HY432Q4nWQaBrFjGQGR+BgghCW97woR9n2+fVII-aAv15X8BUA0kqFAxkSXWCD32g3Y4N8FAkOPOlZEBQptEwvY7wfUF8OzVlCgYT90G-ad+X-SZ8XomimSo0SCnE5iCAOVjENjWNgmgAAJWI9hgd0siqCIyAfL0cg4AByGB4AAa2gVJImgAAVABlaQ7AceTCTA5TGN+OVXA8JT6JU7RDUPWkCBRVYqhuaA5CoDoCmdBIWFQ88oN+ficLwl9IWC7ldiklg+T-AD4tRUxSpKIQcBgWx7A4XZKvI2TKIUwLIoag0OuwFiEPY-ssuwHLuNUgrBKfYqSiIpi4wqqsupqhLTHQpqe1azghp-GSAP8kC+pZAaYKnPYNPgtjrBYAdJrPabeOwubhKvFS1JWg7pOqyZaqyeghB+bQdpa3z2rjTqjrkujCUU+GNnQy6pxGu6JqwR6sD08JImA3Y9o4HqAto8ClpCwQcXCpGINBmKOMBiAksyaAAAUeHXFJMtpbLnoG2bcKEhaygu8rfvM7gubMiIqnwPpfqqiiTuos6NjF6HhpurSxoezHoCm9DBaKgjXw1lhVqwSXpegcz4DlnBOkV9a4fAxHyfNtHtdG+7sGxg3ntB43hdNyEUfFzWrc5sBubth2Fcjv7ldp93lPDxP0e0-X-dxqgImownIZJxYyaCvLuSp9xS8i+nfEkIA)

Comment: Thank you! It works as expected now. Missed it in documentation somehow